# Using Interface Confusing

Tags: oop, interface, dependency-injection, abstraction

I am looking at a framework that put different interfaces to each services such as:

```cs
public interface ICategoryService
{
    Category GetCategoryById(int categoryId);
    void InsertCategory(Category category);
    void UpdateCategory(Category category);
    void DeleteCategory(Category category);

    IPagedList<Category> GetAllCategories(string categoryName = "",
        int pageIndex = 0, int pageSize = int.MaxValue, bool showHidden = false);

    ...
}

public class CategoryService : ICategoryService
{
    public virtual void DeleteCategory(Category category)
    {
        if (category == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("category");

        category.Deleted = true;
        UpdateCategory(category);
    }

    public virtual void InsertCategory(Category category)
    {
        if (category == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("category");

        _categoryRepository.Insert(category);
    }

    public virtual void UpdateCategory(Category category)
    {
        if (category == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("category");

        var parentCategory = GetCategoryById(category.ParentCategoryId);
        while (parentCategory != null)
        {
            if (category.Id == parentCategory.Id)
            {
                category.ParentCategoryId = 0;
                break;
            }
            parentCategory = GetCategoryById(parentCategory.ParentCategoryId);
        }

        _categoryRepository.Update(category);

    }

    ...
}
```

Each entity has one repository that does CRUD operations and also there are some Services that is using these repositories to do some business operations. They also use and IOC container to resolve these dependencies.

When I looked at the services, they have some similar methods and same implementations. So why they dont use an abstract base service and inherit from it to do these similar operations ?

```cs
public abstract class BaseService<T> where T : BaseEntity
{
    void Insert(T t)
    {
         //do some implementation
    }

    void Update(T t)
    {
         //do some implementation
    }

    ...
}
```

While we take advantage of using Interface for testing and abstraction purpose, dont we put too much effort for it ? Is there an better way to implement this approach ?

Comment: The point to your question is unclear. Are you inquiring about a 3rd party library? If so, you should be asking the library writers about their design rationale. Or are you inquiring about a library written by your organization? In which case a more detailed outline of business requirements is necessary before sensible opinions could be ventured. Or are you asking in general about when to use interfaces vs abstract classes?

Comment: Too much effort in using interfaces? I hope not. Without interfaces, we lose fundamental, key, important concepts like polymorphism, dependency inversion, dependency injection, and loose coupling.

Comment: If I use abstract classes instead of Interface for this scenario, what is my loss ?

Comment: A generic base class only makes sense if the implementations largely look the same. If that is not the case, without knowing further details, I'd think a generic interface `IDatabaseService<T>` that is implemented by concrete classes might be a better option.